# Untar fails when it used to work

Tags: r, windows, tar

I use `untar` to decompress `.tar.gz` files which used to work like a charm. However, on the same files ([see file attached](https://github.com/freysimon/ZAMGR/raw/master/inst/extdata/INCA_TT.tar.gz)), `untar` doesn't work anymore.

I use:

```
file = "C:/TEMP/INCA_TT.tar.gz"  # The file attached
untar(tarfile = file, exdir = tempdir())
```

And I get the error:

> tar (child): Cannot connect to C: resolve failed
>
> gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
>
> /i686/tar: Child returned status 128
>
> /i686/tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
>
> Warning messages:
>
> 1: running command 'tar.exe -zxf "C:/TEMP/INCA_TT.tar.gz" -C "C:/TEMP"' had status 2
>
> 2: In untar(filename, exdir = "C:/TEMP") :
>     ‘tar.exe -zxf "C:/TEMP/INCA_TT.tar.gz" -C "C:/TEMP"’ returned error code 2

What could be the reason for this? If I open the `tar.gz` file using `7zip` it works.

Comment: An error code 2 from `tar` is a [fatal error](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_19.html#Synopsis). That would suggest the program is in your `path`, there is a problem with something related to the file, either location, permissions, or other.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can assure I have permission to the file and that the file isn't corrupted since untaring this file used to work.
But for some reason, I cannot find `tar` or `tar.exe` in my `path` envirnonment. On the other hand calling `tar` from a `cmd` window produces the same output as in `R`
I also tried moving the file to another location, but without luck. Is there a way of reinstalling `tar.exe`?

Comment: Your file path would suggest you are using windows, what happens when you execute `tar --help` from the command line?

Comment: There are many ways of having tar loaded on your machine, `cygwin`, `wsl` on win 10, etc.

Comment: I get the help page from tar  saying: "Usage: tar [Option...] [FILE]... GNU 'tar' saves many files ... and so forth.
And yes, I'm using a windows 7 machine

Comment: so you already have tar available... you may need to look back to your other error `gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file`. I still contend there is a problem with the file or accessing it (regardless of the fact that you can perform the task manually with 7zip).

Comment: I moved to another computer and tried to `untar` the same file using the same command. Works.

Comment: I found maybe not the reason, but a solution: I use `tar(tarfile = file, exdir = tempdir(), tar = "internal")`. That works also on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same error, later I found out that I had traversed to c drive (using ../../mnt/c) and tried to pass the full path from the root (which is a mistake for sure) so please check the below 2 points
1: the path (is it an absolute path or relative path)
2: the directory/location from where you are executing this command should be able to traverse along the **path** you passed and be able to find the file at that location
this is one of the solution (there will help if it relates to the above scenario)